# Oracle Jet router go doesn't do anything

Tags: oracle-jet

I am creating a application which consist of 4 routes:

login, home, page1, page2

when I check in login whether a user has been logged in, then it will forward user to home. This works perfectly by getting the router's rootinstance and call go method.

When I check whether user is not logged in on the home page, it have to send the user to the login page. I use the same mechanism as I did above, but it doesn't do anything. The page get loaded and user stays on home. When I add router.sync(); as next command, I get error because sync is undefined. Funny thing is, after the error occurred the router did send me to login.

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, which I solved using the promise that `Router.sync` returns ([router.sync documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Router.html#sync)). Call `Router.sync` in your main view model after you `.configure` the router, and then call your `ko.applyBindings`, routing etc. in the promise's `then` function like this:

```
oj.Router.rootInstance.configure(...);
oj.Router.sync().then(
          function () {
            // bind your ViewModel for the content of the whole page body.
            ko.applyBindings(
              new RootViewModel(),
              document.getElementById('globalBody')
            );
            // navigate the user to login or wherever you want them to be now
            oj.Router.rootInstance.go('login');
          },
          function (error) {
            oj.Logger.error('Error in root start: ' + error.message);
          }
        );
```